# Sharing masks among adjustment layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I wish to apply a curves adjustment and a HSL adjustment to area of an image, and a different curves and HSL adjustment to a different area of the same image.

I could give both adjustments for each area the same mask.

Or I could have three copies of the image, giving the top two the appropriate masks and maskless adjustment layers.

Both seem wasteful.

Is there a way of sharing masks between adjustment layers?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but maybe you could put the adjustment layers in a group and then give the group a layer mask.

Comment: You indeed did understand it because that works. For some reason I thought I'd have to put the image in the group as well, but of course not.

Comment: @Joonas has already given the best solution for this, but this may come in handy in the future:  You can `ALT(Option) + DRAG` masks from one layer to another.  Much the same way this works to clone almost anything in the Adobe Suite, this will clone that layer's mask onto whichever layer you drag it to.

Comment: Nice tip John - I have been in the habit of copy/pasting them.